# Injection of custom CDI scope in @ApplicationScoped bean of Batchlet

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, scope, customization, cdi

I have problems injecting a bean annotated  with my own `@JobScoped` CDI Scope in an `@ApplicationScoped` bean of a `Batchlet` (Batch API).

I have defined the `@JobScoped` annotation :

```
@Documented
@Scope
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface JobScoped
{
}
```

I have registered my custom `JobScopeContext` through a CDI extension.

```
public class JobScopeExtension implements Extension
{
   public void registerJobScopeContext(@Observes final AfterBeanDiscovery p_event, final BeanManager p_beanManager)
   {
      p_event.addContext(new JobScopeContext(p_beanManager));
   }
}
```

And  the `JobScopeContext`, implementing `get` methods of `Context` API to manage creation of my `@JobScoped` bean.

```
public class JobScopeContext implements Context {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * 
     * @see javax.enterprise.context.spi.Context#get(javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual)
     */
    @Override
    public <T> T get(final Contextual<T> p_contextual) {
        // do stuff
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * 
     * @see javax.enterprise.context.spi.Context#get(javax.enterprise.context.spi.Contextual,
     *      javax.enterprise.context.spi.CreationalContext)
     */
    @Override
    public <T> T get(final Contextual<T> p_contextual, final CreationalContext<T> p_creationalContext) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

I will not talk here about the way I manage the lifecycle of my `@JobScoped` beans as it does not matter for my problem.

I now defined my `@JobScoped` bean :

```
@JobScoped
public class MyBeanJobScopedImpl implements MyBeanJobScoped {

    @Override
    public String getId() {
        return "MyString";
    }

}
```

And an `@ApplicationScoped` bean which has the previous bean as a dependency :

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyBeanApplicationScoped {

    @Inject
    private MyBeanJobScoped m_beanJobScoped;

    public String callBeanJobScoped()
    {
        return m_beanJobScoped.getId();
    }

}
```

Here is now the behaviour I observes :

#### Use in JAX-RS resource

If I inject my `MyBeanApplicationScoped` bean in a JAX-RS resource :

```
@Path("custom")
public class RessourceREST {

    @Inject
    private MyBeanApplicationScoped m_beanApplicationScoped;

    @GET
    @Path("testApplicationScoped")
    public String test() {
        return m_beanApplicationScoped.callBeanJobScoped();
    }
}
```

Then every time I call the `m_beanApplicationScoped.callBeanJobScoped()` method, the `Context#get(Contextual)` and `Context#get(Contextual, CreationalContext)` method of my `JobScopeContext` class are called to resolve the injected bean. This is the normal behaviour.

#### Use in a Batchlet (does not work as expected)

Now if I inject my `MyBeanApplicationScoped` bean in a `Batchlet` :

```
@Named("MyBatchlet")
@Dependent
public class MyBatchlet extends AbstractBatchlet{

    @Inject
    private MyBeanApplicationScoped m_beanApplicationScoped;

    @Override
    public String process() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        m_beanApplicationScoped.callBeanJobScoped();
        return "OK";
    }


}
```

The first time the Batchlet is called (launching the job which owns this Batchlet), the the `Context#get(Contextual)` and `Context#get(Contextual, CreationalContext)` method of my `JobScopeContext` class are called to resolve the injected bean.

**But if I call once again the job, the `get` methods of `Context` are never called again. It's as if the `@JobScoped` bean was injected in the @ApplicationScoped bean as an @ApplicationScoped bean.**

**Am I missing something or is there something wrong with my implementation?**

Thanks.

Comment: Just wondering, in your JAX-RS resource, what happens if you give it a scope?  Right now its not a CDI bean (assumption).  Also, what container are you running on?

Comment: I'm on weblogic 12.2.1 but I ahve the same problem on Wildfly. 
I solved the problem replacing the `@Scope` annotation of my JobScoped scope by `@NormalScope`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem replacing the `@Scope` annotation of my `JobScoped` scope by **`@NormalScope`**.